# PySpark process all numpy files in folder

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I know that I can process all text files with Spark using the following command.

```
alltexts = sc.textFile("hdfs://mydir/*", 1584)
relevant = alltexts.mapPartitions(lambda x: my_func(x)).collect()
```

However, how do I process a directory containing compressed numpy arrays (in the format .npz)?

**Edit:**

I've managed to get a file list and process it using

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs    
filelist = hdfs.ls("/user/my_user/my_dir", recursive=True)
rdd = sc.parallelize(filelist).mapPartitions(lambda x: my_func(x))
```

However, when I try to load the numpy files in `my_func()` using `np.load()` I get the following error. Any suggestions?

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'hdfs://.../my_dir/file.npy`
```

Comment: Parallellize the file locations and map over the file location with a python function that reads and processes data

Comment: Thanks, but how do I parallellize the file locations? I've tried `alltexts = sc.textFile("hdfs://machineaddress.edu/my_dir", 1584)`, but that just yields a bunch of nonsense. I agree, that if I can just get a list of files from HDFS onto the SparkContext I should be good.

Comment: pydoop my help you with that http://crs4.github.io/pydoop/tutorial/hdfs_api.html#hdfs-api-tutorial

Comment: I've tried it, but I'm having some issues. Please see the updated post.